# Understanding WORD PTR

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm, x86-16

I have some 16bit source code I am trying to understand.

I have.

```
unsigned short addr, d;

addr = &d;

8D46FA // LEA AX,WORD PTR [d]
8946FC // MOV WORD PTR [addr],AX
```

addr becomes 0x159A

Why does addr = 0x159A and not 0xFA46 ?

This question has been put on hold, but the answer has been given and I've accepted it. I wasn't asking how registers work, (which seems like people thought I was, my question was straightforward and simple, why does it compile the above ASM as that and not what I might otherwise be expecting.)

Comment: `WORD PTR [d]` is verbose way of saying `[d]` since the size of the data doesn't matter in getting its address. Would be the same as saying `LEA AX, [d]` which moves the address of `d` to AX.  In `MOV WORD PTR [addr],AX` the size of AX is known to be 16-bits to again `WORD PTR [addr]` is a verbose way of saying `[addr]` so is the same as `MOV [addr], AX` . The debugger is providing the size probably more for information(size of a short is a 16-bit WORD).

Comment: The generated code seems to be properly moving the address of `d` to `addr` . I assume the variables here are in a function and thus on the stack. `addr` is not in a fixed point in memory.

Comment: The debugger has displayed the address of `d` and `addr` in a neat  form but the address really ends up being `lea ax,[bp-0x6]` and `mov [bp-0x4],ax` which is normal for stack based variables. Anything with a base of `bp` is automatically assumed to be in the stack segment so would have also been the same as `lea ax,ss:[bp-0x6]` and `mov ss:[bp-0x4],ax` . 0xFA = -6 and 0xFC = -4. If `addr` becomes 0x159a then that would imply the address of `d` is `ss:[0x159a]`

Comment: You would likely see something different (and more to what you expected) if you moved the variable `d` to global scope (outside of a function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disassembly is a bit confusing. These addresses were actually relative to `BP`, which is normal for local variables. `lea` has a mod R/M byte and a mod R/M byte of `46` in 16bit addressing [means `BP+sbyte`](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm).

The whole point of `lea` is that it uses the memory operand encoding, so it definitely needs mod R/M.

Comment: I thought the RegModR/M byte might have come into it. I'm handwriting some compiling code so I have to understand this in detail. (It's no more than about 10 or so lines.)

Comment: Thankyou, I will go back to the 86 specification and read a little more.

Comment: 0x15A0 (addr) - 0x159A (BP) = 0xFA (-0x06); 89 (89 r/m8, r8); 46 (01 disp8) 000 (AL) 110 ([BP]+disp8) FA (-0x06) = 8946FA.